# Pyramid and Cassandra don't work properly

Tags: python, cassandra, pyramid, asyncore

I am using **Pyramid (1.5.7)**, **waitress (0.8.9)** with **Cassandra (2.2.0)**. It seems like Waitress and Cassandra driver are using both asyncore and somehow they are stepping on each others toes. This is my code on the **app/__init__.py** file:

```
import logging.config
from .action.context import root_factory
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.query import named_tuple_factory


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application."""

    # support logging in python3
    logging.config.fileConfig(
        settings['logging.config'],
        disable_existing_loggers=False
    )
    config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory=root_factory)
    # Retrieves connection to Cassandra (Non SQL database)
    def get_non_sql(request):
        cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'], port=9042)
        session = cluster.connect('app')
        def disconnect(request):
            cluster.shutdown()
        request.add_finished_callback(disconnect)
        return cluster.connect('app')

    #Adding scheduler configuration
    config.configure_celery(global_config['__file__'])
    config.add_request_method(get_non_sql, 'non_sql', reify=True)
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Generated errors:

```
2015-07-27 12:24:36,779 ERROR [waitress][cassandra_driver_event_loop] Socket error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python3.4/site-packages/waitress-0.8.9-py3.4.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 167, in handle_read
    data = self.recv(self.adj.recv_bytes)
  File "python3.4/asyncore.py", line 379, in recv
    data = self.socket.recv(buffer_size)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
2015-07-27 12:24:37,079 ERROR [waitress][MainThread] Unexpected exception when flushing.
  File "python3.4/site-packages/waitress-0.8.9-py3.4.egg/waitress/server.py", line 154, in run
    use_poll=self.adj.asyncore_use_poll,
  File "python3.4/asyncore.py", line 208, in loop
    poll_fun(timeout, map)
  File "python3.4/asyncore.py", line 145, in poll
    r, w, e = select.select(r, w, e, timeout)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
2015-07-27 12:33:32,649 DEBUG [cassandra.io.asyncorereactor][cassandra_driver_event_loop] Asyncore event loop ended
```

Does someone know a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Waitress** and **cassandra-driver** were using the same socket. I've deleted the version **0.8.9** of waitress and installed the latest development version (**master** branch)

```
pip uninstall waitress
pip install git+git://github.com/Pylons/waitress@master
```

The asyncore socket has been changed in this version so it works perfectly.
Nonetheless I recommend using [libev](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/2.5/python-driver/reference/nonPythonDependencies.html) instead, it seems to have better performance than asyncore. In OS X it's as easy as installing the **libev** library:

```
brew install libev
```

Right after doing this, install the **cassandra-driver** (It will detect the **libev** library automatically)

```
pip install cassandra-driver
```

And then just use the **LibevConnection** class:

```
from cassandra.io.libevreactor import LibevConnection 
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster 


cluster = Cluster() 
cluster.connection_class = LibevConnection 
session = cluster.connect()
```